# OptaPlanner Execution server failed to convert string () to type (java.time.LocalDateTime)

Tags: rest, optaplanner

Trying to setup an employee rostering from "Try Samples" from Workbench and trying to setup this for accessing the solution through REST APIs.
I am facing an issue while uploading my data set using POST and I have listed below in detail what I tried and faced.

Before that, when I register (PUT) my solver config.xml I am getting NOT_SOLVING as status. Is this the actual status we will get?

The error is parsing the date format.

```
<startTime>2017-01-01T00:00</startTime>
```

and tried different formats like below but it didn't help.

```
 <startTime>2017-01-01 00:00</startTime>
```

Environment Details:

```
wildfly-10.0.0.Final
kie-server(Execution Server) - 7.5.0.Final 
Workbench(for WildFly10)
```

PUT: http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/employeerostering/solvers/employeerosteringSolver

Request Body:

```
<solver-instance>
  <solver-config-file>employeerostering/employeerostering/EmployeeRosteringSolverConfig.solver.xml</solver-config-file>
</solver-instance>
```

GET: http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/employeerostering/solvers/employeerosteringSolver/bestsolution

Response Received:

```
<solver-instance>
  <container-id>employeerostering</container-id>
  <solver-id>employeerosteringSolver</solver-id>
  <solver-config-file>employeerostering/employeerostering/EmployeeRosteringSolverConfig.solver.xml</solver-config-file>
  <status>NOT_SOLVING</status>
  <score />
</solver-instance>
```

POST: http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/employeerostering/solvers/employeerosteringSolver/state/solving

Request Body:

```
<planning-problem class="employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster">
  <employeeList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>John</name>
      <skills>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
          <name>consulting</name>
        </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
          <name>translation</name>
        </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
      </skills>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>Ann</name>
      <skills>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
      </skills>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>Paul</name>
      <skills>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
          <name>maintenance</name>
        </employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill>
      </skills>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>Carla</name>
      <skills>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
      </skills>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>Brian</name>
      <skills>
        <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../../employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
      </skills>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
      <name>Unskilled</name>
      <skills class="empty-list"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee>
  </employeeList>
  <shiftList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-01T00:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-01T07:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-01T08:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-01T15:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-01T16:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-01T23:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-02T00:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-02T07:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-02T08:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-02T15:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-02T16:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-02T23:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-03T00:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-03T07:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-03T08:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-03T15:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-03T16:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-03T23:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-04T00:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-04T07:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-04T08:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-04T15:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-04T16:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-04T23:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-05T00:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-05T07:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-05T08:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-05T15:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
      <timeslot>
        <startTime>2017-01-05T16:00</startTime>
        <endTime>2017-01-05T23:59</endTime>
      </timeslot>
      <requiredSkill reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift>
  </shiftList>
  <skillList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill[2]"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill reference="../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[3]/skills/employeerostering.employeerostering.Skill"/>
  </skillList>
  <timeslotList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[2]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[3]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[4]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[5]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[6]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[7]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[8]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[9]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[10]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[11]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[12]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[13]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[14]/timeslot"/>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot reference="../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[15]/timeslot"/>
  </timeslotList>
  <shiftAssignmentList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[3]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[4]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[5]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[6]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[7]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[8]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[9]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[10]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[11]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[12]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[13]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[14]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
      <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[15]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
  </shiftAssignmentList>
  <dayOffRequestList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.DayOffRequest>
      <employee reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee"/>
      <date>2017-01-01</date>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.DayOffRequest>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.DayOffRequest>
      <employee reference="../../../employeeList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Employee[2]"/>
      <date>2017-01-02</date>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.DayOffRequest>
  </dayOffRequestList>
</planning-problem>
```

Response Received: 500 Internal Server Error

Below is the log captured from console.

```
 -------------------------------: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.IllegalStateException
cause-message       : Failed to convert string (2017-01-01 00:00) to type (java.time.LocalDateTime).
class               : java.time.LocalDateTime
required-type       : java.time.LocalDateTime
converter-type      : org.kie.soup.commons.xstream.LocalDateTimeXStreamConverter
path                : /planning-problem/shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift/timeslot/startTime
line number         : 49
class[1]            : employeerostering.employeerostering.Timeslot
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift
class[3]            : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
class[4]            : employeerostering.employeerostering.EmployeeRoster
version             : 7.5.0.Final
```

Comment: I created an issue to [improve the error message by showing the IllegalStateException message](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-939).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with dateformat given. I gone through by decompiling the jars where the issue is causing.

Actually the date format it expects is:

```
<startTime>2017-01-01T16:00:01.001</startTime>
```

but what I see in many examples is:

```
<startTime>2017-01-01T00:00</startTime>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with this sample on Optaplanner 7.9.0 but the error is different

> "Unexpected error during processing: Can't unmarshall input string"

The solution xml submitted was copied from this [jboss](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.0/html/creating_and_solving_the_employee_roster_problem_for_red_hat_business_optimizer_using_decision_central/wb-employee-rostering-solver-configuration-proc#wb-employee-rostering-register-solver-proc) article (the same error I get if using the xml above).